# void function parameter in both the definition and declaration? Or just one?

Tags: c, gcc

There are a ton of posts explaining why explicitly doing `foo(void)` is better than `foo()` because it specifies that there are no function arguments instead of an unknown amount.

However, I cannot seem to find if it's best practice to put void in both the header file declaration **and** the source file definition such as:

**foo.h**

```
void foo(void);
```

**foo.c**

```
void foo(void)
{
     return;
}
```

---

OR

---

**foo.h**

```
void foo(void);
```

**foo.c**

```
void foo()
{
     return;
}
```

Which one is better practice, and is there a specific reason to do one over the other?

Comment: Primarily opinion based. Both the same. Any other opinion is wrong ;-)

Comment: @John3136 Really? "primarily opinion based"? Something that the standard for the past 27 years explicitly documents as discouraged and "may be considered for withdrawal in future revisions" is not a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old-style function declarations and definitions with empty parentheses are an obsolescent feature ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.11.6, 6.11.7). There are hardly any good reasons to use them.

Use `(void)` consistently, not `()`.

Answer (score 4):

In your specific case it makes no difference, however it is a good habit to write:

```
void foo(void)
{
```

because there may come a time when you write a function body without also having a separate prototype beforehand,  and this serves as a prototype whereas `void foo() {` does not.